# Схожие css-свойства

Tags: html, css

```
visibility: hidden;
display: none;
opacity: 0.0;
```

В чем разница между этими css свойствами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***visibility:hidden***
 прячет еллемент, но он по прежнему может участвовать в расположении html елементов, т.е. он есть но его не видно. 
***opacity:0.0***
 примерно тоже самое, только к тому-же свойство CSS3 т.е. не является кроссбраузерным.
 
***diplay:none***
елемент не отображается и никак не влияет на отображение видимых елементов.

Comment: Отличие opacity от visibility в том, что opacity - это прозрачность, можно выставить определенное значение.

Comment: Тут указан параметр 0.0 КагБы, а opacity:0.0 это примерно тоже самое что visibilite:hidden, только не везде работает, еще вопросы?

Comment: У меня есть панель. И мне нужно получить её ширину, не отображая саму панель. Так вот, ширину можно определить только если панель приаттаченна и со свойством `opacity:0.0` или `visibility:hidden`, но при `diplay:none` ширина панель всегда ноль (это всё про IE9). Поэтому я хотел узнать, нет ли еще каких приколов с этими свойствами.

Comment: Значит, разница только в кросс-браузерности.

Comment: Вы задали вопрос и получили ответ, выше вы никак не описывали того что вам нужно. Для решения этой проблемы, если visibility:hidden мешает рассположению елементов, то просто надо его абсолютно спозиционировать, таким образом елемент не будет ни начто влиять и можно будет узнать ширину<br>
Еще как варинат - height:0px;